# Refresh DataGridView vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, datagridview

I have DataGridView which doesn't refresh. I was hoping to be able to refresh it by clicking on the 'Refresh' button.

My database is called 'ProjectDatabase' and the table I want to use is called 'SWOT'.

I'v tried a few ways but none have been working, and if it does work then I get new issues like every time I click on refresh it duplicates the data. Im using a MS Acess Database.

I tried the below coding, it refreshes, but duplicates the data x2 every time I click Refresh:

```
Private Sub btnRefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRefresh.Click
    Refreshdata()
End Sub

Dim myConnection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\ahmed\OneDrive\Desktop\ProjectDatabase2003.mdb")
Dim DS As DataSet = New DataSet
Dim DA As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim tables As DataTableCollection = DS.Tables
Dim source1 As New BindingSource()

Private Sub Refreshdata()
    DA = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from SWOT", myConnection)
    DA.Fill(DS, "SWOT_Report")
    Dim view1 As New DataView(tables(0))
    source1.DataSource = view1
    DataGridView1.DataSource = view1
    DataGridView1.Refresh()

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try setting DataGridView1.DataSource to Nothing before assigning view1 to it.

Comment: Tried DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing before source1.DataSource = view1 but still duplicating

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191666/how-to-refresh-my-datagridview-after-i-add-new-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is clear your `DataTable` before filling it again. .NET doesn't do that automatically.

```
Private Sub Refreshdata()
    '-- clear table before filling
    If DS.Tables("SWOT_Report") IsNot Nothing Then DS.Tables("SWOT_Report").Rows.Clear

    DA = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from SWOT", myConnection)
    DA.Fill(DS, "SWOT_Report")
    Dim view1 As New DataView(tables(0))
    source1.DataSource = view1
    DataGridView1.DataSource = view1
    DataGridView1.Refresh()

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, managed to fix the issue by adding DS.Clear() before DA.Fill(...). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are overcomplicating your code with the use of the `BindingSource`, `DataSet`, `DataAdapter`, and `DataTable` member (class scope) variables.

For the member variables, strip them down to these two:

```
Dim ConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\ahmed\OneDrive\Desktop\ProjectDatabase2003.mdb"
Dim swotBindingSource As BindingSource
```

Please note, the `myConnection` object has been removed and replaced with a **Connection String variable** instead

In the Forms `New()` method add:

```
swotBindingSource = New BindingSource()
DataGridView1.DataSource = swotBindingSource
```

This will setup your `DataGridView` to have the `swotBindingSource` as its DataSource. The BindingSource can be of use later on when it comes to filtering data.

And, finally change the `RefreshData` sub to be:

```
Private Sub Refreshdata()
    Dim swotDataTable As New DataTable

    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)
        Using DA As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM SWOT", conn)
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            DA.Fill(ds, "SWOT_Report")
            swotBindingSource.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

When the `swotBindingSource` gets updated, you should automatically see the updates in the DataGridView.

---

It is likely you will also have to make other changes to the rest of your code due to the lack of `myConnection` object, you will be better off creating a new Connection object (similar to how it is done in the `RefreshData` sub) each time you need to use the database rather than creating one when the application starts and re-using the same connection.